# Automatically hide corresponding rows based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I tried writing macros wherein rows are hidden based on a cell value (which is a Data Validation dropdown):

[image: Example Data]

Using the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("C15") Then

        BeginRow = 17
        EndRow = 25
        ChkCol = 4

        For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
            If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Cells(15, 3).Value Then
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Else
                Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Next RowCnt
    End If
exitHandler:
  Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

It is doing the thing I need but the problems I'm facing are, it is taking time for any change in C15 (actual data has around 100 rows) and also when I'm trying to make any changes in rest of the sheet, it throws an error -

> "Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch".

I have no macros experience and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could you please help me correct the code. If there is a better way to achieve the same task in a more efficient way, please do let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Looping through a few 100 (or even a few thousand) rows checking the hidden property will run fast enough.  Key points are to limit the checking to only the required cells, and do the Hide/Unhide in one operation (this is the slow bit if done a row at a time)

Using the logic:

- If Cell `C15` changes, check the whole list, or
- If one or more cells change in the list `D17:D25` (or larger) process only changed cells
- Build a reference to rows that must change hidden state, and set the Hidden property for the whole range

This code runs virtually instantly on a List range of a few 1000 rows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cl As Range
    Dim rTest As Range, vTest As Variant
    Dim rList As Range
    Dim rHide As Range, rUnhide As Range

    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set rTest = Me.Cells(15, 3) ' Cell to compare to
    Set rList = Me.Range("D17:D25") ' List of cells to compare to the Test cell

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, rTest) Is Nothing Then
        ' Test cell has changed, so process whole list
        Set rng = rList
    Else
        ' Only process changed cells in the list
        Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, rList)
    End If

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        ' there is somthing to process
        vTest = rTest.Value
        For Each cl In rng.Cells
            If cl.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                ' the row is already hidden
                If cl.Value = vTest Then
                    ' and it should be visible, add it to the Unhide range
                    If rUnhide Is Nothing Then
                        Set rUnhide = cl
                    Else
                        Set rUnhide = Application.Union(rUnhide, cl)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                ' the row is already visible
                If cl.Value <> vTest Then
                    ' and it should be hidden, add it to the Hide range
                    If rHide Is Nothing Then
                        Set rHide = cl
                    Else
                        Set rHide = Application.Union(rHide, cl)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next

        ' do the actual hiding/unhiding in one go (faster)
        If Not rUnhide Is Nothing Then
            rUnhide.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
        If Not rHide Is Nothing Then
            rHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Autofilter` which will be quick.

You can easily change  BeginRow, EndRow and ChkCol  to adjust range and code still works.

Set to `Criteria1:="<>" & Target`  if you want to show only those not like the selected item.

0.008 seconds for 10000 rows.

[image: Filter]

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim BeginRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim ChkCol As Long
    Dim RowCnt As Long

    With ActiveSheet

        If Target.Address = Range("C15").Address Then

            BeginRow = 17
            EndRow = 25
            ChkCol = 4

            Dim filterRange As Range

            Set filterRange = .Range(.Cells(BeginRow - 1, ChkCol - 1), .Cells(EndRow, ChkCol))

            filterRange.AutoFilter

            filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= Target 

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This code will also run into an error 13.  You also do not need Activesheet as the code is in the worksheet module and in this case Activesheet is clearly defined. But the idea using an autofilter is much quicker and nicer than the TO's approach to hide the rows

Comment: I have set it to answer as shown. If there was no data that would be a different matter perhaps.

Comment: Select A1:A3 and then press delete

Comment: Because the event is also triggered if you change a cell or several cells  different than C15 and you have to make sure the event also works in this case.

Comment: The Event will trigger everytime you change a cell

Comment: Using .Address fixes it. I forgot to put that in.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the error you need to use the error handler. The error will occur in case you select more than one cell and try to delete them

```
    Option Explicit

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const BeginRow = 17
    Const EndRow = 25
    Const ChkCol = 4

    Dim RowCnt As Long

        On Error GoTo exitHandler

        Application.EnableEvents = False


        If Target = Range("C15") Then

            For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
                If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value = Cells(15, 3).Value Then
                    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Next RowCnt
        End If

exitHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True

    End Sub
```

**EDIT** Based on QHarr's idea to use the Autofilter

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Const BeginRow = 17
Const EndRow = 25
Const ChkCol = 4
Dim RowCnt As Long


    On Error GoTo EH

    'If you want to prevent error 13 you could uncomment the following line
    'If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target = Range("C15") Then

        Dim filterRange As Range
        Set filterRange = Range(Cells(BeginRow - 1, ChkCol), Cells(EndRow, ChkCol))
        filterRange.AutoFilter
        filterRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Target

    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**EDIT2** The reason for the run-time error 13 is the line Target = Range("C15"). In case you select more than one cell you compare a range with a value because Range("C15") always returnes the value of that cell. As QHarr changed his code after our discussion to Target.Address = Range("C15").Address this error cannot occur any longer.

Comment: The OP only wants to filter in relation to a drop down selection. There is no row deletion.

Comment: Wonder why the error even occurred. As you mentioned, it happens when I do operations on multiple cells, irrespective of the range that is being affected by the code. Can you explain why this happens? I have implemented QHarr's code and it works perfectly and doesn't even throw run-time error.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Find` method may be quicker for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo exitHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = "$C$15" Then
        Rows("17:25").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Me.Range("D17:D25").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

exitHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Rather than iterating over every row one-by-one, this version first hides all rows in the range, and then unhides the appropriate row, if found.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, Lee! This works perfectly and is a lot quicker. Even the error doesn't pop-up, though not sure why.

Comment: @Srikiran You're welcome! Note that I am validating the `Address` property of the `Target` range against `$C$15` as opposed to comparing a range with a range - I believe this was originally causing your error.